# How do I get the index to be less than the size

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing, size

I am having trouble getting the index to be less than the size of the arrayList so that i can deal the cards. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Deck {
   ArrayList<Card> unusedCards = new ArrayList<Card>();
   ArrayList<Card> usedCards = new ArrayList<Card>();
   Card newCard = new Card();
   Random rand = new Random();


//Creates a Deck of 52 randomly ordered card objects (No repeats)
public Deck() {
     for (int i = 0; i <= 52; i++) {
         while (unusedCards.contains(newCard)) {
             newCard = new Card();
         }
         unusedCards.add(newCard);
     }
}
//shuffles the arraylist of the deck of cards, making it so the cards are dealt in a different order
public void shuffle(){
    Collections.shuffle(unusedCards);
}

//Boolean is true when the Unsed deck has no cards left
public boolean isEmpty(){
    if (unusedCards.size() == 0) return true;
    else return false;
}

//returns an arraylist containing the specified number of cards
public ArrayList<Card> Deal(int numToDeal){
    ArrayList<Card> DealCards = new ArrayList<Card>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numToDeal; i++){
        int index = rand.nextInt(50);
        DealCards.add(unusedCards.get(index));
        usedCards.add(unusedCards.get(index));
        unusedCards.remove(unusedCards.get(index));
        }

    return DealCards;
}
```

}

I keep getting this error when i try to deal a number of cards:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 48, Size: 48
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at nnajiO.Deck.Deal(Deck.java:41)
at nnajiO.CrazyEights.main(CrazyEights.java:26)
```

Thanks if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 int index = rand.nextInt(unusedCards.size());
```

This way you will generate a random number that will always be in range of the size of unused cards

Answer (score 0):

You're putting 53 cards in the deck.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 52; i++) {
```

The range of indexes in an array is `0 .. length-1`.  Therefore you want to be using the `<` operator in the above statement rather than the `<=` operator.

The other problem is similar. You are removing cards from `unusedCards` while using a static random range:

```
int index = rand.nextInt(50);
```

Under the circumstances, that should be changed to the following to avoid choosing an index that is out of range:

```
int index = rand.nextInt(unusedCards.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

On this line you are removing elements from your list:

```
unusedCards.remove(unusedCards.get(index));
```

However, within the same for loop, you are retrieving elements from the same list and ultimately, the code attempts to access an element at an index that was removed in a previous iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

When you are dealing cards, you're always pulling a random card from 0-49, regardless of the number of cards left in `unusedCards`:

```
public ArrayList<Card> Deal(int numToDeal){
    ArrayList<Card> DealCards = new ArrayList<Card>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numToDeal; i++){
        int index = rand.nextInt(50);  // this should check the number of cards left
        DealCards.add(unusedCards.get(index));
        usedCards.add(unusedCards.get(index));
        unusedCards.remove(unusedCards.get(index));
        }

    return DealCards;
}
```

The more cards you try to deal, the more likely you are to try to deal one "past the end" of the unused deck.

Make your loop pick a random card based on the number of remaining cards instead of `50`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numToDeal; i++){
    int index = rand.nextInt(unusedCards.size());
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this part of your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numToDeal; i++){
    int index = rand.nextInt(50);
    DealCards.add(unusedCards.get(index));
    usedCards.add(unusedCards.get(index));
    unusedCards.remove(unusedCards.get(index));
    }
```

You are creating a random index in the range 0 to 49. At first, you have 53 elements in your array, so this would work. But you see the `remove` there at the end? It means that one card is removed from the list, so now it has 52 elements.

The next time you do that, 51 remain, and so on. Eventually you are left with less than 49 elements. At this point, the number `49` is not a valid index. So if the random number generator happens to generate it, you're going to get the error you got.

Instead, you should limit the `index` to `unusedCards.size()`.

By the way, if you shuffle the cards, there is really no need to go through the `unusedCards` list randomly. It's already in random order. Just deal the last `numToDeal` items and remove them.